# React Redux reducer not returning

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an application that has to return only future events. I am able to parse through my firebase realtime db and return only future events in my action. It then passes this array of data to my reducer. In my reducer, I am logging the payload. The console log displays the data I want. Now in my component screen, I console log to see what data I should see from the reducer and it is empty.

My action:

```
    export const getAllEvents = () => {

        var currentTime = Date.now();

          return (dispatch) => {
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('Events/');
            ref.orderByChild("availableSpots").on("value", function(snapshot) {

                snapshot.forEach(child => {
                    var time = child.val().epochTime;

                   if (currentTime < time) {
                        console.log("Events redux: ", child.val());

                        dispatch({ type: GET_EVENT_LIST, payload: child.val() });
                    }
                })
                });
              });


          }
      }
```

As you can see I am console logging the child.val() which comes out as expected below:

[image]

Now I have this hooked up to my reducer via dispatch.

```
import { GET_EVENT_LIST } from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    eventList: [],
};

const eventListReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case GET_EVENT_LIST:
            console.log("action count", action.payload);
            return { ...state, eventList: [...state.eventList, action.payload] };

        default:
        console.log("default ");
            return state;
    }
};

export default eventListReducer;
```

As you can see the console log of the action.payload is being logged and produces an expected result:

[image]

Now back in my component screen:

```
    import { getUserThunk, getAllEvents } from '../actions';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';

    class Home extends Component {

      componentWillMount() {

        console.log("Component will mount");
        this.props.getUserThunk();
        this.props.getAllEvents();
      }
    render() {
      console.log("usersadf ", this.props.userReducer)
      console.log("Props in home ", this.props.eventListReducer)
      return (
        //some return code here

      );
    }

export default connect(
    state=>({userReducer: state.userReducer, eventListReducer: state.eventListReducer}), 
    { getUserThunk, getAllEvents }
  )(Home);
```

Now as you can see I do have different redux action and reducer hooked up and it comes through. However, the one in question returns empty.

[image]

Comment: My reducer is in a combined reducer which is attached to the store at my root component. I am able to use it for other actions however for this specific action its not working. I feel like I have it set up just like my other actions/reducers etc

Comment: Is your `getAllEvents` action getting the `dispatch` prop? I dont see it passed as an argument in the code you have provided. Also, if you want to get the firebase data only once when the action is called, use `ref.orderByChild("availableSpots").once` instead of `ref.orderByChild("availableSpots").on`, because `on` will add a listener and will be called every time data changes.

Comment: Yes in the first block of code I have: `dispatch({ type: GET_EVENT_LIST, payload: child.val() }); `

Comment: For some reason in my reducer if I use `return state.arr.push(action.payload);` it works. However, I do not want to push into the array I want to use the standard which is `return { ...state, eventList: [...state.eventList, action.payload] };`